# Is it possible to 'git restore --work-tree.. ' a file with a relative filename?

Tags: git, relative-path

I am trying to restore a file to a different directory given the file's relative filename:

```
git --work-tree some/directory restore -s HEAD ./numbers.txt
```

Yet, this command fails with *error: pathspec './numbers.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git*.

I am a bit puzzled because `git restore`, without the `--work-tree` option does not fail:

```
git restore -s HEAD ./numbers.txt
```

So, is it possible to use `git --work-tree dir restore` with a relative filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's giving you trouble is that when you specify an explicit work tree all paths are interpreted relative to that work tree, `.` isn't relative to your current directory any more, it's that work tree. So Git's looking for a toplevel `numbers.txt`.

When you just want to put specific content there without really checking it out, use `git show`. Here, `git show @:./numbers.txt >some/directory/numbers.txt`.